# Problemas de conexão com o banco de dados Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando criar um sistema para faculdade, porém estou com um erro ao tentar conectar com Mysql, estou utilizando PHP e Xampp.

Erro:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_conect() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Cursos\Testes\conecta.php on line 2

Já tentei algumas soluções que funcionaram com outros mas não funcionaram comigo:

Alterações no PHP.ini:

- `extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"` - Está de acordo com o que informam.
- `extension=php_mysql.dll` e `extension=php_mysqli.dll` - Descomentadas.
- Apache *reiniciado* após as alterações.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser feito?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Você não definiu no  function mysqli_conect() o host para ele conectar.

Comment: Você errou na hora de digitar a função. Não é `mysqli_conect`, e sim `mysqli_connect`. Faltou um "n"!

Comment: Realmente, o erro era este mesmo, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como o usuário acima disse `mysqli_conect` está mal escrita, escreve-se `mysqli_connect`, daí teres o retorno : `Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_conect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cursos\Testes\conecta.php on line 2` que diz que a função não existe ou não está definida.
Veja se isso lhe ajuda.

```
<?php
 $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'Usuario_', 'Senha_', 'banco_de_dados_');
 if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
   die("Erro: ". mysqli_error());
 }
 echo 'Conexão bem sucedida';
 mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Realmente, o erro era este mesmo, muito obrigado pela ajuda.